# Free application center

Tags: windows, gratis, command-line, launcher

What I am looking for is free software to manage applications to use in an enterprise environment. That management software (let's call it the Application Center) should meet the following requirements:

- Define the applications (with their command-line parameters) in an XML file or any kind of configuration structure. The configuration should preferably be on a network share and not on a local computer.
- The applications to manage are partially local and partially network apps.
- The user just has this Application Center on his desktop. When it starts it presents the list of applications that were added in the configuration.
- The user can then start the application he wants and it runs with the defined parameters.

Comment: Who installs the software on the User's PC? Why is it tagged command-line if there shall be a GUI displayed to the user?

Comment: installation is not the scope here. The GUI should be so the user has the option to select what he would like to use (as in what application to start). The command line parameters are sometime necessary for the software to run correctly.

Comment: So you want a replacement for the Windows start menu?

Comment: I know you can do that with a folder on the windows desktop. But explain that to a s'''' manager :)

Comment: Is http://www.lighttek.com/talisman.htm similar to what you need?

Comment: Or http://sharpe.sourceforge.net/